# Refactoring a python project that has a lot libraries that have "from smthng import *"

Tags: python, import, refactoring, python-import, zen-of-python

I start a python project that continues developing. It has 10 local libraries. Each of them call each other "from name import *". For a example from main:

```
from name3 import *
from name2 import *
from general_functions import *
from messages import *
from network import *
from keyboard_functions import *
from process_functions import *
from name4 import *
from settings import *  # settings
```

According to zen of python, explicit is better than implicit. Also due to understanding and debugging project, i need explicit the importing methods and variables.

Also other libraries use the same import methods. I feel all libraries import all libraries by the "*".

I try to refactoring by the hand

```
from debug_functions import (print_log, print_log2, debug_functions_initilizer, debug_prints_abbrev, print_setting_info,
                             print_error, print_warn, print_error_warning_count_of_this_process, print_debug,
                             print_performance_report)
```

like this.

But i stopped when i see deep.

For example a.py import exp1 library. In the b.py, it call `from a.py import *`. So in the b.py, exp1 library can be used without import exp1. So in the b.py, if i convert `from a.py import *` to explicit form, `from a.py import something`, there occury errors that depend on exp1 library. There are a lot of example like that.

How do I solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

What did I?
I import libraries with their own methods, variables to each library.
For example I have a.py, b.py and c.py libraries.
I import a.py and b.py with their own all methods to c.py. Like that,

`from a import foo, bar`
`from b import exp, solv`

In b.py, in the same way,
`from a import foo, bar`
`from c import sa, as`

After that for now, libraries have necessary methods from real owner, not a 3rd library.

In the end, I delete unused methods in libraries.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to fix this, whoever wrote this mess left you with a mess unfortunately. This is *exactly* why starred imports, especially on a mass scale like this, are considered a bad practice.

Comment: There may be some IDE refactoring tool for this, but I'm not familiar with any, but maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a easy solution, but this might help a little. Install pylint and set tests on all modules for "variable not defined"

1. Create a module, say, "temporary.py" and have all your "from xyz import *" from all files in this place.

```
from name3 import *
from name2 import *
from general_functions import *
from messages import *
from network import *
from keyboard_functions import *
from process_functions import *
from name4 import *
from settings import *
```

2. Remove all "from xyx import *" from all other modules and replace with single line "from temporary import *

This will help against depedencies of all modules on each other(as all modules will now depend on "temporary.py

3. Now start with the first import "from name3 import *" in temporary.py. Remove this import and run the pylint tests. Fix all modules with failures by adding the implicit imports after "from temporary import *"
4. Follow this step for all other imports
5. Once all done, remove "from temporary import *" from all files.

Note: There is a caveat though. If 2 modules have same variable/function defined, say "my_function", and module C imports both modules, then it uses "my_function" from the last import. You wont be able to identify such issues if any and might end up using the wrong function.

Comment: I try to what you advice. But in the way, I think a easy way. I add it on my question.